# why the armv7s / arm64e architectures don't increase the package size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, assembly, arm64, armv7

we know that, if valid architectures in build settings of Xcode project  are armv7 and arm64, it will generate a fat binary file which contains both armv7 and arm64 executable instruction, and the binary file size will doubled. but why the armv7s / arm64e architectures don't perform like that?